# How do I create a shortcut to an executable with variables? Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: steam, shortcuts, alias

How can I create a shortcut to a file with a variable in Ubuntu Server 20.04? The user account that will execute the shortcut does not have Sudo permissions.

Here is the path with a variable I want to execute. Note the space between 64 and KF.

```
/home/steam/kf2/Binaries/Win64/KFGameSteamServer.bin.x86_64 KF-BioticsLab?Difficulty=2
```

My purpose is to be able to easily launch multiple game servers running off different ports with the ports specified as variables on the executable rather than having different config files. I have experimented with ln and alias with limited success.

Comment: You can just add the working command as is on the `Exec=` line of the .desktop file.

Comment: I created a .desktop file with a single line Exec=/home/steam/kf2/Binaries/Win64/KFGameSteamServer.bin.x86_64 KF-BioticsLab?Difficulty=2 but when I try to execute the file (as a non-sudoer) I receive the error "Permission denied". When I execute it as a sudoer, I receive the error "command not found".

Comment: 1) How do you execute a .desktop file as a sudoer?? 2) It is also difficult to understand how you can obtain "command not found" if you supply the full (correct) path to the executable. 3) A .desktop file with a single line cannot work. It needs at least a few lines to be a valid launcher.